# Android SlidingMenu NoClassDef exception

Tags: android, exception, slidingmenu

I have looked at similar questions on the forum and they have not helped in resolving my issue.

I'm trying to get a slidingMenu implementation working using the following code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try{
            slidingMenu = new SlidingMenu(this);
            slidingMenu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
            slidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
            slidingMenu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_shadow_width);
            slidingMenu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.abs__ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo);
            slidingMenu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
            slidingMenu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
            slidingMenu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
            slidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.slidemenu);

//          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
//              getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
//          }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "SlideMenu malfunction!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

But I get the following error stack:

```
09-25 02:09:23.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7672): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-25 02:09:23.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7672): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.view.ViewConfigurationCompat
09-25 02:09:23.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):     at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.initCustomViewAbove(CustomViewAbove.java:167)
09-25 02:09:23.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):     at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.<init>(CustomViewAbove.java:157)
09-25 02:09:23.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):     at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.<init>(CustomViewAbove.java:152)
09-25 02:09:23.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):     at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.<init>(SlidingMenu.java:209)
09-25 02:09:23.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):     at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.<init>(SlidingMenu.java:192)
09-25 02:09:23.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):     at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.<init>(SlidingMenu.java:171)
09-25 02:09:23.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):     at com.icerge.revivaltimes.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
09-25 02:09:23.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
09-25 02:09:23.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
09-25 02:09:23.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
09-25 02:09:23.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
09-25 02:09:23.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
09-25 02:09:23.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-25 02:09:23.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
09-25 02:09:23.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
09-25 02:09:23.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-25 02:09:23.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-25 02:09:23.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
09-25 02:09:23.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-25 02:09:23.042: E/AndroidRuntime(7672):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MANIFEST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.icerge.revivaltimes"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.my.project.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**UPDATE[Build path error messages]:**

```
MotionEventCompat cannot be resolved to a variable  CustomViewAbove.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib    line 614    Java Problem
MotionEventCompat cannot be resolved    CustomViewAbove.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib    line 600    Java Problem
MotionEventCompat cannot be resolved    CustomViewAbove.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib    line 632    Java Problem
MotionEventCompat cannot be resolved    CustomViewAbove.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib    line 631    Java Problem
MotionEventCompat cannot be resolved    CustomViewAbove.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib    line 636    Java Problem
The constructor SlidingActivityHelper(SlidingFragmentActivity) is undefined SlidingFragmentActivity.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 21 Java Problem
MotionEventCompat cannot be resolved    CustomViewAbove.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib    line 635    Java Problem
MotionEventCompat cannot be resolved to a variable  CustomViewAbove.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib    line 681    Java Problem
MotionEventCompat cannot be resolved to a variable  CustomViewAbove.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib    line 647    Java Problem
FragmentActivity cannot be resolved to a type   SlidingFragmentActivity.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 30 Java Problem
FragmentActivity cannot be resolved to a type   SlidingFragmentActivity.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 11 Java Problem
MotionEventCompat cannot be resolved    CustomViewAbove.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib    line 691    Java Problem
MotionEventCompat cannot be resolved    CustomViewAbove.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib    line 690    Java Problem
FragmentActivity cannot be resolved to a type   SlidingFragmentActivity.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 20 Java Problem
MotionEventCompat cannot be resolved    CustomViewAbove.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib    line 705    Java Problem
FragmentActivity cannot be resolved to a type   SlidingFragmentActivity.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 50 Java Problem
MotionEventCompat cannot be resolved    CustomViewAbove.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib    line 759    Java Problem
MotionEventCompat cannot be resolved    CustomViewAbove.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib    line 760    Java Problem
FragmentActivity cannot be resolved to a type   SlidingFragmentActivity.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 39 Java Problem
MotionEventCompat cannot be resolved    CustomViewAbove.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib    line 736    Java Problem
MotionEventCompat cannot be resolved to a variable  CustomViewAbove.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib    line 758    Java Problem
MotionEventCompat cannot be resolved    CustomViewAbove.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib    line 769    Java Problem
FragmentActivity cannot be resolved to a type   SlidingFragmentActivity.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 75 Java Problem
MotionEventCompat cannot be resolved    CustomViewAbove.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib    line 780    Java Problem
MotionEventCompat cannot be resolved    CustomViewAbove.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib    line 761    Java Problem
MotionEventCompat cannot be resolved to a variable  CustomViewAbove.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib    line 764    Java Problem
MotionEventCompat cannot be resolved    CustomViewAbove.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib    line 838    Java Problem
FragmentActivity cannot be resolved to a type   SlidingFragmentActivity.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib/app    line 149    Java Problem
MotionEventCompat cannot be resolved    CustomViewAbove.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib    line 843    Java Problem
MotionEventCompat cannot be resolved    CustomViewAbove.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib    line 783    Java Problem
MotionEventCompat cannot be resolved    CustomViewAbove.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib    line 837    Java Problem
KeyEventCompat cannot be resolved   CustomViewAbove.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib    line 944    Java Problem
KeyEventCompat cannot be resolved   CustomViewAbove.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib    line 946    Java Problem
MotionEventCompat cannot be resolved    CustomViewAbove.java    /slidingmenu/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib    line 844    Java Problem
```

Comment: post activity_main.xml

Answer (score 3):

Go to your `slidingMenu` library in your workspace > `Properties` > `Java Build Path` > `Order and Export` tab > Make sure `android-support-v4` is checked

Clean your project. This should be fixed.

**EDIT:** Just noticed you have ActionBar sherlock in yoru manifest. In this case you need to do the same steps for your actionbarsherlock library in your workspace. Then you need to remove `android-support-v4` from the slidingmenu library. Add sliding menu as an Android Library dependency in actionbarsherlock. Then ONLY add actionbarsherlock as an android library to your application.

[image]

Your own project should have ActionBarSherlock referenced in its own properties like above. `ActionbarSherlock` should be the only project with `android-support-v4.jar` in the libs folder.

Finally **Clean - Rebuild**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's helped to make sense of things and I've followed it to the letter. BUT, I got a lot of build path errors which I have pasted into my original question. My slidingmenu library has a red cross against it while my project and the actionbarsherlock library have red exclamation marks.                    Can you offer any further assistance?

Comment: Don't worry about the sliding menu library and the red cross, it will still work. You just need to go to Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries for both your own project and ActionbarSherlock remove whatever has a red marker on it. That should fix the problem. If it still doesn't, remove android-support-v4.jar from ActionbarSherlock, get the latest version from your own adt installation on your machine (I believe it will be in sdk\extras\android\support) and copy it into the libs folder of ActionbarSherlock. Make sure there are no red markers in Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries